# How can Log Time the user shut down the application

Tags: android, kotlin

friends.
I'm looking for a way to get a log of the time the user turned on and off the application.

When I receive an notification from the backend, I want to express that there is a new announcement if there is a new notification within the time when the user turns it on and off.

What should I do?

I have time when the notification made.

turn on time - 2021-07-21 13:02:06

turn off time - 2021-07-21 13:11:07

new notification time - 2021-07-21 16:08:43

then we have 1 new notification.

I want users to get a log of the time they turn on and off the app.

Comment: How about you log the startup event. I guess, you really don't want the startup time, but rather the time, the userinterface was loaded, and the preexisting notifications have been loaded? My next question is: What would you use a shutdown time for? Do you also want to reprint all notifications since the user used the app the last time? What if a user uses the app for the first time? Also, there are different 'starts': https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/vitals/launch-time

Comment: First, Thank's for your answer.


I was going to increase the count if I had time in between, but I was wondering if there was another way. I think onStart, onStop will be O.K.? 
I'm trying to use this to save and compare dates with Shared Preferences.

Comment: Hi! I understand I don't need endTime. I use two of arraylist, in onStart. then compare there and if between notification date will be +count. It's be O.K.?